Projecting Google Play books onto Android televisions
I wanted to post this on Android Enthusiasts stack exchange.
I wanted to know why it is not possible to project (using Chromecast, or a similar technology), a Google Play book onto an Android television screen.
You could have pinch to zoom or drag on the Android device to have everything displayed onto television.
The same goes for web pages, which could readjust to size on the television screen.
With current screen mirroring technology the screen size is just mirrored and a subset of the entire television screen is displayed, but I can't have the area enlarged and zoomed.
Also, I am not sure whether television screen resolution would be adequate, but theoretically,I think, it would.
I would like to be able to read a Google Play book on the television and control panning and zoning from my phone.
Thanks.
